# Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was writing the following code

```
SELECT
    customer_Id,
    DOB,
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, CONVERT(date, Customer.DOB, 103), GETDATE()) AS [Age IN Months],
    Gender,
    city_code,
    Qty,
    (total_amt - (Rate + Tax)) AS [Total_sale_amt]
FROM 
    Customer
JOIN 
    Transactions ON Customer.customer_Id = Transactions.cust_id
ORDER BY 
    [Age IN Months] DESC;
```

Ended up with following error msg

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

Please let me know as in this section `

```
( total_amt - ( Rate + Tax ) ) AS [ Total_sale_amt ]
```

I intend to to get a sales figure column additional to all other columns.

Below is what my table looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzjeI.png)

Thank you!

Comment: provide the table schema of your `Transactions` table. Looks like column is `VARCHAR`. You will have to use `CONVERT` to convert it into numeric and then perform addition or subtraction

Comment: Here ( total_amt - ( Rate + Tax ) ) one of the column or some columns seems to be varchar. Convert it to numeric.

Comment: @semicolon - Thank you  . Opened in design view and changed the data type and  it worked. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Seems like  one of the column or some columns  `( total_amt - ( Rate + Tax ) )` is `varchar`. `Cast/Convert` all the columns to `int/Float/Decimal` according to your requirement.

For the below query, i assume your `totalamt, Rate, Tax` are `varchar` fileds.

```
 SELECT
        customer_Id,
        DOB,
        DATEDIFF( MONTH, CONVERT ( date, Customer.DOB, 103 ),GETDATE ( ) ) AS [ Age IN Months ],
        Gender,
        city_code,
        Qty,

        ( cast(total_amt as FLOAT) - ( cast(Rate as float) + cast(Tax  as float)) ) AS [ Total_sale_amt ]
    FROM Customer
    JOIN Transactions
        ON Customer.customer_Id = Transactions.cust_id
    ORDER BY [ Age IN Months ] DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only subtract operator you have is:

```
(total_amt - (Rate + Tax)) AS [Total_sale_amt]
```

This suggests that one of these is a string -- and cannot be implicitly converted.  I would suggest looking for these values:

```
select total_amt, rate, tax
from ?  -- don't know which table these are in
where try_convert(decimal(20, 4), total_amt) is null or
      try_convert(decimal(20, 4), rate) is null or
      try_convert(decimal(20, 4), tax) is null;
```

This will show the offending values.  You will need to fix the data or ask another question on how to fix the data -- once you know what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks I went to Design view and changed the data type which fixed my issue